# Adding Entities to Vault Namespaces,Groups, or Policies Terraform

Tags: terraform, vault, terraform-provider-vault

I'm having an issue with the Vault Terraform. I am able to create Entities, Namespaces, Groups, and policies but linking them together is not happening for me. I can get the policy added to the group just fine, but adding members to that group I cannot.

Here's what I have so far:

```
# module.users returns vault_identity_entity.entity.id
data "vault_identity_entity" "user_lookup" {
  for_each    = toset([for user in local.groups : user.name])
  entity_name = each.key

  depends_on = [
    module.users
  ]
}

# module.devops_namespace returns vault_namespace.namespace.path
resource "vault_identity_group" "devops" {
  depends_on = [
    vault_policy.policy
  ]
  name = "devops_users"
  namespace         = module.devops_namespace.vault_namespace
  member_entity_ids = [for user in data.vault_identity_entity.user_lookup : jsondecode(user.data_json).id]
}

resource "vault_identity_group_policies" "default" {
  policies = [vault_policy.gitlab_policy.name]
  exclusive = false
  group_id = vault_identity_group.devops.id
}
```

What I need to do is create a namespace and add users and a policy to that namespace.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the issue that you have? Are there any errors?

Comment: the issue is that entities aren't being added to the group

Comment: So there are not any errors?

Comment: no errors come up. The output says the group gets created `vault_identity_group.devops_users: Creation complete after 0s` but the users aren't in the group

Comment: Ok, and what happens if you try the following: `member_entity_ids = [for user in values(data.vault_identity_entity.user_lookup) : jsondecode(user.data_json).id]`?

Comment: It came back with the same results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246121/discussion-between-stacker-and-marko-e).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resource "vault_policy" "namespace" {
  depends_on = [module.namespace]
  name       = "namespace"
  policy     = file("policies/namespace.hcl")
  namespace  = "devops"
}

resource "vault_identity_group" "devops" {
  depends_on = [
    module.users
  ]
  name              = "devops_users"
  namespace         = module.devops_namespace.vault_namespace
  policies          = [vault_policy.gitlab_policy.name]
  member_entity_ids = [for user in module.users : user.entity_id]
}
```

By referring the users the module created I was able to achieve the correct result.

Since the module created the users from `locals` and the data resource was trying to pull down the same users, the extra data resource section wasn't needed.

Thank you Marko E!